# Cassandra NoHostAvailableException; How to set up Native protocol Cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I know this question has been asked around the internet a lot, including stackoverflow, but so far none of the solutions have worked for me. I'm thinking it might be a weird error with the .yaml file

1) I know its not a firewall issue, as I've tested the connection between the two nodes

2) I've increased the timeouts

3) I've set rpc address to 0.0.0.0 and the public ip

4) I've set the broadcast address to the public ip

Couple irregularities

1) I noticed on my first cluster (which works) that this is the output for cqlsh:

Connected to cas1 at 127.0.0.1:**9042**.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.3 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | **Native protocol v3]**

Now, on my new cluster it is:

Connected to Test Cluster at localhost:**9160**.
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.16 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | **Thrift protocol 19.39.0**

Is this normal? My set up process wasn't different.

2) When I put in the listen address in the cas1 cluster, the ip address was white. When I put in the listen address in the Test Cluster, the ip address becomes red with one of the "." white. I'm not an expert on this stuff, but I know that isn't normal. I've tried c/p and it hasn't helped

3) I also noticed that the Test Cluster didn't have "broadcast_rpc_address" setting which the cas1 cluster did, I c/p that over (obv changed the address) but that didn't work as well

So both of my settings are exactly the same in the two cassandra clusters:

listen address: private.ip

start_native_transport: true

native_transport_port:9042

start_rpc:true

rpc_address: public.ip //also tried 0.0.0.0

rpc_port:9160

broadcast_rpc_address:private ip //also tried public

4) In the meantime, I'm going to try to re install cassandra, so far in the details I haven't seen anyway on how I can configure if its native or thrift protocol, please let me know if there is a way I can specify this.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is normal for Cassandra 2.1.3 and Cassandra 2.0.16. Cassandra 2.1.X uses native protocol for cqlsh, and 2.0.X uses thrift. Your setup process had to be a little different :-)

Comment: it was different as in one was for ec2 and one was for a private cloud node, but I believe I went through the same steps. It's weird because I did the 2.0.x one after the 2.1.3 one. Do you know why I might be getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

All modern versions speak both thrift (9160) and native (9042).

Native is used for cqlsh in 2.1+, where cqlsh in 2.0 prefers thrift.

You've somehow mixed versions - probably because you did an apt/yum install without paying attention to the versions. It's worth noting that 0.0.0.0 IPs are usually a shortcut that doesn't necessarily work - get the right IPs in there, and make sure it's binding to the right IPs.